# Why is the toilet tank still running after replacing rubber gasket?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

The toilet tank was leaking water, so I replaced the rubber gasket at the bottom of the drain valve with a new identical one (size and shape). However, the toilet is still running. If I manually press down the drain valve really hard, then the leaking stops.

Nothing seems to be  wrong with the valve itself, it can move up and down without any problems. (* Well, it WAS ok until I accidentally broke it while experimenting :S)

I noticed, however, that the new gasket already accumulated some limescale. Is it possible that the fix counterpart of the gasket should be replaced as well? Is that even possible without replacing the whole tank? (It seems to me not possible to remove it at all.)

In other words, I should decide if I need a new valve or a whole new tank?
(Still in other words: can it be that replacing the gasket is not enough, but replacing the valve is?)

Comment: If you think the seat of the flush valve is bad, you can repair or replace that part. It would likely be next to impossible to replace just the tank, so do not break it. To change the flush valve, the tank must be removed (on two-piece toilets). There are a multitude of types, make sure you use compatible replacement. Take pictures then go to a good plumbing shop, before you tear anything apart. This is a big job.

Comment: I would replace the flush valve. But you might also be able to adjust it. Depending on the type, if you have the old plastic bulb (ball), then just bend the line so the ball is down in the water more, shutting off the water sooner. If you have the newer valve system, adjust the height of the ring.